# Does an electric crepe maker require a hood and ventilation?

Tags: equipment, crepe

I have an electric crepe maker and was wondering whether it is required to have a hood with ventilation to the outside of the building?

Comment: Are we talking about a electric crepe maker that makes one crepe at a time? It might be helpful if you specify the exact model of the crepe maker or provide a link to it on the web. (Hurry before SOPA and PIPA ends it all...lol jk)

Comment: In general it's a pretty safe bet that something that's sold to normal consumers as a kitchen counter appliance doesn't need special ventilation.

Answer (score 5):

Doubtful (assuming we're talking about something along the lines of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ZM4P7C), if its some kind of commercial unit doing 10 at a time, get a hood).

Crepes don't typically output enough fumes or smoke of any kind in quantity and an electric crepe maker should be even better on that front.  There may be a bit of steam, but nothing that should warrant an vent outside.